# How can I change the event symbols in the Vuetify v-date-picker component?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

The `v-date-picker` component can show dots for events. I would like to indicate availability (our use case involves visualization of cloud cover percentage on a specific day). How would I go about changing the shape of these dots?

From [image: Vuetify 2 date picker] to [image: Modified Vuetify 2 date picker with changed symbols]

Ideally I would use a slot to change the visualization of the events, but unfortunately there is no slot for the event dots.

Answer (score 2):

The [`:event-color`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-event-color) prop is used to determine the CSS class attached to the events. You can pass in a function that takes the date and returns a class string for a single event or an array of class strings for the corresponding number of events.

So you have to define css classes for your shapes, then the event color function can figure out for each date how many events there are, and for each event the color and shape.

Check the snippet for a simple example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-date-picker
            v-model="date"
            :events="arrayEvents"
            :event-color="eventColorFunction"
            no-title
          />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      arrayEvents: [...Array(26)].map(() => {
        const day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)
        const d = new Date()
        d.setDate(day)
        return d.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
      }).sort(),
      date1: (new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    eventColorFunction(date){
      const length = this.arrayEvents.reduce((count,d) => d === date ? count+1: count,0)
      return Array.from({length}, () => this.buildRandomEventClass())
    },
    buildRandomEventClass(){
      const form = this.randomSelect(['', 'semi-circle', 'square', 'quarter-circle'])
      const color = this.randomSelect(['purple', 'brown', 'pink', 'orange'])
      return color+' '+form
    },
    randomSelect(arr){
      return arr[arr.length*Math.random()|0]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-date-picker-table__events > div.square{
  border-radius: 0;
}
.v-date-picker-table__events > div.quarter-circle {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}
.v-date-picker-table__events > div.semi-circle {
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```